# Selenium Grid for stress/performance testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, load-testing, performance-testing, selenium-grid

Im new to using Selenium Grid so I don't really know that much about it. What im trying to do is simulate 400 users using my website. I can create the test script that simulates the users actions but im not sure how to use Selenium grid to simulate 400 users using the website at once. Any help or useful tutorials would be appreciated.

At the moment im using selenium webdriver and firefox driver to simulate one users actions. All my tests are being run through eclipse.

Comment: You can use JMeter to stress test your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is a Grid  implementation but not using a standard webbrowser.  I think what you want is to just do a multi-threaded GhostDriver test by registering GhostDrivers to your Grid nodes.  You can use TestNG to fork the threads using a TestNG instance generating class factory.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I ended up using JMeter to stress test my website.

Comment: Sure, you can do it that way also but its a trade-off.

Comment: what do you mean its a trade off? In what sense? I don't know much about this so please forgive my ignorance,

Comment: In some ways, JMeter makes things easier but in other ways it doesn't.   Also, using JMeter you are not testing an actual browser, nor are you testing "javascript operating the page".  You lose out because  you are simply testing get/response and so your clients are not "truly" acting like actual clients.  I could point out more differences as well but comments are not the place to discuss.